# ● libvirtd.service ,Active: inactive (dead), Initialization of QEMU state driver failed: invalid argument: Failed to parse user 'libvirt-qemu'

Tags: gpu, qemu, minikube, kvm, libvirt

When I check status of libvirtd using the cmd: `sudo systemctl status libvirtd` the o/p is as follows:

```
    ● libvirtd.service - Virtualization daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2021-07-22 18:00:59 EDT; 1min 4s ago
TriggeredBy: ● libvirtd-admin.socket
             ● libvirtd.socket
             ● libvirtd-ro.socket
       Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
             https://libvirt.org
    Process: 1717 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/libvirtd $libvirtd_opts (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1717 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 22 18:00:59 eb2-2259-lin04 systemd[1]: Starting Virtualization daemon...
Jul 22 18:00:59 eb2-2259-lin04 systemd[1]: Started Virtualization daemon.
Jul 22 18:00:59 eb2-2259-lin04 libvirtd[1717]: libvirt version: 6.0.0, package: 0ubuntu8.11 (Christian Ehrhardt <christian.ehrhardt@canonical.com> Tue, 05 Jan 2021 13:48:48 +0100)
Jul 22 18:00:59  libvirtd[1717]: hostname: eb2-2259-lin04
Jul 22 18:00:59 eb2-2259-lin04 libvirtd[1717]: invalid argument: Failed to parse user 'libvirt-qemu'
Jul 22 18:00:59 eb2-2259-lin04 libvirtd[1717]: Initialization of QEMU state driver failed: invalid argument: Failed to parse user 'libvirt-qemu'
Jul 22 18:00:59 eb2-2259-lin04 libvirtd[1717]: Driver state initialization failed
Jul 22 18:00:59 eb2-2259-lin04 systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Succeeded.
```

The status is always inactive(dead). And I get lines `invalid argument: Failed to parse user 'libvirt-qemu'`  , `Initialization of QEMU state driver failed: invalid argument: Failed to parse user 'libvirt-qemu'` and `Driver state initialization failed`

I also tried `sudo systemctl start libvirtd`
and `sudo systemctl status libvirtd`    but the issue doesn't get resolved.

I was actually installing KVM2 driver for GPU support within minikube following the link [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation][1]. According to the link KVM2 is successfully installed in Ubuntu if `virsh list --all` cmd does not return an error. For me all the steps returned no error except for the `virsh list --all` returned the following error.

```
error: failed to connect to the hypervisor
error: Cannot recv data: Connection reset by peer
```

and sometimes returns the following error

```
error: failed to connect to the hypervisor
error: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': Connection refused
```

When I start minikube with kvm2 as the driver using the command `minikube start --driver kvm2`I get the following error

```
   minikube v1.15.1 on Ubuntu 20.04

  Exiting due to GUEST_DRIVER_MISMATCH: The existing "minikube" cluster was created using the "virtualbox" driver, which is incompatible with requested "kvm2" driver.
  Suggestion: Delete the existing 'minikube' cluster using: 'minikube delete', or start the existing 'minikube' cluster using: 'minikube start --driver=virtualbox'
```

Please suggest me how to start minikube with kvm2 as driver.

Answer (score 0):

The error states:

```
Jul 22 18:00:59 eb2-2259-lin04 libvirtd[1717]: invalid argument: Failed to parse user 'libvirt-qemu'
```

Create the user `libvirt-qemu`, create the groups `libvirt-qemu`, `libvirt`, and `libvirtd`.
Add the user `libvirt-qemu` to the group `libvirt-qemu`.

This is a soft-fix. For more details please refer this [link](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=768000)